# Typeahead for XPiNC

Tags: xpages

I try to enable typeahead for an input field to lookup usernames from names.nsf. My names.nsf contains over 1000 person documents.

When using my application from Web browser, typeahead works fine (capable to lookup any usernames from the names.nsf).

However, when using my application from Notes client (i.e. XPiNC), typeahead only tries to lookup from the first 50 person documents in the names.nsf, so the remaining usernames would never get displayed from the typeahead result. How can I fix this problem?

```
<xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1" ignoreCase="true" id="typeAhead1">
    <xp:this.valueList>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:return @Name("[Abbreviate]",@DbLookup(new Array(@DbName()[0],"names.nsf"),"($VIMPeople)",getComponent("Username").getSubmittedValue(),1,"[PARTIALMATCH]"));}]]>
    </xp:this.valueList>
</xp:typeAhead>
```

Kevin

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered today that typeahead works fine with my XPiNC app too. Unfortunately, I can't say exactly what has caused the change in behavior.

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your minChars to 3. This will reduce the huge performance hit on requesting an update every time a single user types a character in the field.

I'd also recommend to use @DbColumn instead of @DbLookup.

Lastly rule out if the code is the issue, or the typeahead. Although the purpose of a typeahead is not to give you every result, but to narrow down based on what the user types.

If you must get every result, I'd recommend to use the Name Picker component instead.